# Adjunctions between $\mathcal{A}_{\infty}$-categories

Tags: ct.category-theory, homological-algebra, infinity-categories

Is there a theory of homotopy coherent adjunctions between  $\mathcal{A}_{\infty}$-categories? By this I mean at least a definition of what an adjunction is and a construction of the corresponding unit/counit.

I couldn't find any reference in the literature. Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Riehl and Verity study the free homotopy coherent adjunction as a simplicial category, see below; it should be possible to make the correct definition via this and by taking an appropriate nerve of the $A_\infty$-category or an appropriate realization of the simplicial category.  https://arxiv.org/abs/1310.8279